# Sampling from share transition of population distribution

Tags: r, distributions, inference, simulation

Dears,

I have this data below, which represents a distribution of population across 8 groups in time 1 and consequent time 2. (time1 > time2). I would like to sample using these 2 inputs, it this sampling below appropriate?

data:

```
                 from         to
group 1 17.785825 24.6877200
group 2 19.024499 19.1316200
group 3 25.700736 28.7450607
group 4 18.872761 16.4958496
group 5  9.509484  6.6171471
group 6  3.732614  2.4078783
group 7  2.786355  1.4408675
group 8  2.587725  0.4738568
> colSums(data.in)
from   to 
 100  100
```

step 1:

estimate the density: `density(as.numeric(data.in[i,]))`

step 2:

`base:::sample(as.numeric(data.in[j, ]), N, replace=TRUE) + rnorm(N, 0, list.d[[j]]$bw)`

The final outcome of weighted simulated `rate` result is not so plausible since its too wide (interval).

[image]

**Full replication:**

```
data.all <-
    structure(
        list(
            grade = 1:8,
            rate = c(0.001, 0.0025, 0.0063, 0.0156,
                     0.0391, 0.0977, 0.2441, 0.6104),
            from = c(
                0.177858249529814,
                0.190244992816841,
                0.257007364840541,
                0.188727613609983,
                0.0950948446116216,
                0.0373261406418749,
                0.0278635485813682,
                0.025877245367956
            ),
            to = c(
                0.246877199949458,
                0.191316200481528,
                0.287450607239773,
                0.164958495898585,
                0.0661714712058581,
                0.0240787825807411,
                0.0144086750749326,
                0.00473856756912408
            )
        ),
        class = "data.frame",
        row.names = c(
            "group 1",
            "group 2",
            "group 3",
            "group 4",
            "group 5",
            "group 6",
            "group 7",
            "group 8"
        )
    )

data.in <- data.all[c(-1,-2)] * 100
data.in

# sampling group level

list.d <- list();
new.df <- list();

for(i in 1:nrow(data.in)){
    list.d[[i]] <- density(as.numeric(data.in[i,]))
}


for(j in 1:nrow(data.in)){
    new.x <- base:::sample(as.numeric(data.in[j, ]), N, replace=TRUE) + rnorm(N, 0, list.d[[j]]$bw)
    new.df[[j]] <- data.frame(grade=j, dist.sim=new.x, nsim=1:N);
    
    if(!FALSE){    
        hist(new.x, prob=TRUE, col="blue")
        lines(density(new.x, na.rm = TRUE), col="red", lwd=2)
    }
    
}



rx <- do.call(rbind, new.df)
rx$dist.sim <- rx$dist.sim/100 
rx

# plot distribution across rating groups using the simulation 

par(mfrow=c(2,4))
with(rx, by(rx, grade, function(x) hist(x$dist.sim, col="blue")))


# get data

rx.rate <- merge(rx, data.all[c(1,2)], by="grade");
head(rx.rate)

# simulation

sim.rate <- with(rx.rate, by(rx.rate, list(nsim), function(x) with(x, crossprod(dist.sim, rate))))


portfolio.rate.sim <- data.frame(port.pd=t(rbind(sim.rate)), row.names = NULL)

# final results

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(sim.pd ~ 1, data=portfolio.rate.sim, pch=19, col="blue", ylab="rate")
abline(h=with(data.all, crossprod(from, rate)), col="red", lwd=3)
abline(h=with(data.all, crossprod(to, rate)), col="orange", lwd=3)
```